# Xpages Repeat Controls Tabular display

Tags: nested, xpages, repeat

I have a situation wherein I need to display all documents in view. Issue is I need to display multivalued fields (can be achieved by modifying view column to display new line). Now issue comes when a column value is also multivalued. E.g. first column is created by looping through 50 fields (single value) and second column is created by looping through corresponding  50 fields but these fields are multivalued.
I am looking for ideas about how to nest repeats in this case. Issue is in first repeat I get the handle of documents but in nested one i am not able to get this handle to be able to loop through fields. And it is not simply one column or value I want to display, there are 4-5 such columns.
Any ideas are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a better question will be how to keep reference to same document in nested repeats??

Comment: Provide more details. The question is generic enough for "but that is not what I want" comments. How about amend the question with a sample how the HTML sent to the browser should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start looking at a repeat control, not a view control. Have the outermost control loop through the entries in the view and populate the data source of a containing panel with a Notes document. Then inside the panel you only refer to the inner document data source.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to create a table where in I can sort the columns. and I wanted to avoid using external javascript for doing that.

Comment: You WANT to use the JavaScript for sorting. Check the series on the Dojo grid. That might be what you need.